# How can I get values from Html Tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to get some data from html tags in a web page. For example I have a web site that's got "www.example.com/test.html", this is text which I want to split. I want to first URL, First text thats between in first span tags and last text that's between the last span tags.

How can I do this with C# ASP.NET 2.0 (not 3.5)?

```
<a class="tablolinkmetin" target="_blank" href="http://www.iwantthisurl.com/test/2010/subat/12022010_adli_krrnme.htm">
  <img alt=icon src="images/icon/ok.gif" border=0 width="7" height="8">
  <span class=tablolink>
    <span class="genelgeler_mbaslik">I want this text.</span>
  </span>
  <span class="tablolinkaltyazi"><br>and i want here</span> 
</a>
<img src="images/icon/cizgi.png" width="260" height="1"><br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to have a look at:

- [**Html Agility Pack**](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

---

here is the sample from codePlex.com

> ```
>  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
>  doc.Load("file.htm");
>  foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
>  {
>     HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
>     att.Value = FixLink(att);
>  }
>  doc.Save("file.htm");
> ```

---

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you give the controls an id and set them to runat="server" you should be able to reference them directly in your code.

So your page should look like this:

```
<a id="myanchor" runat="server" class="tablolinkmetin" target="_blank" href="http://www.iwantthisurl.com/test/2010/subat/12022010_adli_krrnme.htm"> 
  <img alt=icon src="images/icon/ok.gif" border=0 width="7" height="8"> 
  <span class=tablolink> 
    <span id="firstSpan" runat="server" class="genelgeler_mbaslik">I want this text.</span> 
  </span> 
  <span id="secondSpan" runat="server" class="tablolinkaltyazi"><br>and i want here</span>  
</a> 
<img src="images/icon/cizgi.png" width="260" height="1"><br>
```

Comment: i cant change any value cuz html file that i want to parse is not mine.Its another site's page.I wanna get this tags values and use that values in my site.